# Where do the Swap values come from?

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, swaps

In this [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdd6203c4718d7611b5e1d014301ecf84ebb110e5e599c6ec041b5513e696c28f), there is a `Swap` event:

```
amount0In: 0
amount1In: 61415
amount0Out: 14972458620320
amount1Out: 0
```

It says that `0.00061415` of POOCOIN is being traded for `0.00001497245862032` BUSD.

However, the `amount1In` value is not mentioned elsewhere in the logs, i.e. I would expect there to be a transfer of `61415` POOCOIN to [BUSD/POOCOIN LP](https://bscscan.com/address/0x92e8f7f2652cf7cff062ac899cf3a62736afb3f9#readContract), but such does not exist.

Where does the 61415 value come from?

Here is [another example transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xfcef7bd68ecb5bbcb69d6799214290d033d26570ea2c2760518171cb75a20039#eventlog).

```
amount0In: 0
amount1In: 3645739352956685
amount0Out: 1736897306606464
amount1Out: 0
```

Despite `amount1In: 3645739352956685`, there is no mention of Transfer for amount of `3645739352956685`.

Comment: Your link to the tx does not work.

Comment: @Undead8 link corrected.